# Forwarding signals in bash script which is submitted on the cluster

Tags: bash, unix, signals, mpi, cluster-computing

I have a `launch.sh` script which I submit on the cluster with

```
bsub $settings < launch.sh
```

This `launch.sh` bash script looks simplified as the following:

```
function trap_with_arg() {
    func="$1" ; shift
    for sig ; do
        echo "$ES Installing trap for signal $sig"
        trap "$func $sig" "$sig"
    done
}
function signalHandler() {
    # do stuff depending in what stage the script is
}

# Setup the Trap
trap_with_arg signalHandler SIGINT SIGTERM SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2 

./start.sh
mpirun process.sh
./end.sh
```

Where process.sh calls two binaries (as an example) as

```
./binaryA 
./binaryB
```

My question is the following:
The cluster already sends SIGUSR1 (approx. 10min before SIGTERM) to the process (I think this is the `bash` shell running my `launch.sh` script).

At the moment I catch this signal in the `launch.sh` script and call some signal handler. The problem is, this signal handler only gets executed (at least what I know) after a running command is finished (e.g. that might be `mpirun process.sh` or `./start.sh` )

How can I forward these signals to make the commands/binaries exit gracefully. Forwarding for example to `process.sh` (`mpirun`, as I experienced, already forwards somehow these received signals (how does it do that?)
What is the proper way of forwarding signals, (e.g. also to the binaries `binaryA, binaryB` ?
I have no really good clue how to do this? Making the commands execute in background, creating a child process?

Thanks for some enlightenment :-)

Answer (score 0):

From bash manual at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html:

*If Bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, **the trap will not be executed until the command completes**. When Bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the wait builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the wait builtin to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.*

Thus, the solution seems to place commands in background and use "wait":

```
something &
wait
```